# html login form not able to generate any post data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, passport.js

i have put my login form inside a bootstrap modal component.Upon entering the values inside the input fields and clicking submit, nothing happens and the modal simply closes. Inside my inspect element under the networks tab, I do not see any post request being made.
have used passport-local for authorisation and mysql as database.
Here is my html snippet

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="login" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="login modal">Login</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <form method="post" action="/login"></form>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Email login">Email address</label>
              <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="Email login" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
              <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Password login">Password</label>
              <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="Password login" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input type="checkbox" name="remember" class="form-check-input" id="remember">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Remember Me</label>
            </div>
            <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button> -->

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and here is the route.js code

```
route.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('login')
})
route.post(
    '/login', 
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '../chat',
        failureRedirect: '/', 
       failureFlash: false, 
       badRequestMessage: 'Please enter your account credentials to login.'
    }), 
    function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.param('remember'));
        if(req.isAuthenticated(req, res)) {
            res.redirect('../chat');
        } else {
            var errors = req.flash('error');
            if(errors) {
                assign['errors'] = errors;
            }
            res.render('index.html', {errors: errors});
        }
    }
);
```

here chat is the folder in my parent directory where i want to redirect the user after a successful login.
Please look into this as soon as possible.I have been trying to debug this since about 40 days.I know it could be a minor syntax error which has croosed my mind.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

just remove  ( data-dismiss="modal" ) from submit button, data-dismiss is closing your popup before execution.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the closing form tag here:

```
<form method="post" action="/login"></form>
```